# OS, modifiable from the inside

Tags: operating-system, self-modifying

Is there any minimal open source OS which can be modified from the inside when running? In educational purposes. I would like something like a built-in WYSIWYG editor with a `reload modified system module` button and an option to run with previous failsafe configuration on boot.

Comment: lol 'run with previous failsafe configuration on boot' - AKA 'after my change crashes the OS:)

Comment: @MartinJames yes, I meant exactly this :)

Comment: You need a kernel mode debugger. They exist.